# Delphi - Setting the ShowModel value mrNone closes the Form

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-7

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. I open Form2 from Form1. 
I have 3 buttons in Form2. OK, Cancel and Load. I have set up mrOK for OK button, mrCancel for Cancel button and mrNone for Load button. 
When I click Load, I want to load a List of items in the form. However, when I click the Load button, the items are loaded but the form is immediately closed.

Here is the Code. 
In Form1,

```
procedure TForm1.Configure
var
  TheForm : TForm2;
  reply   : TModalResult;
begin
  try
    // Some logic
    Reply   := TheForm.showModal;
    if Reply = mrOk then
    begin
      //Some logic
    end;
    //Some more smts
  finally
    FreeAndNil(TheForm);
  end;
end;
```

In Form2, there is some logic for LoadClick button event. 
Form2 Logic

```
procedure TForm2.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 Alist : TStringList;
begin
     if DirectoryExists(DataDir) then
     begin
     try
           for i:=1 to cboList.Items.Count -1 do
           begin
                Response := MessageDlg('Do you want to insert into the list', mtConfirmation,[mbYes,mbNo], 0);
                if Response = mrYes then
                begin
                     InsertNewItem(cboList.Items[i]);
                end;
                if Response = mrNo then
                begin
                     MessageDlg('Not added to the list', mtWarning , [mbOK], 0);
                end;
           end;
      finally
      AList.Free;
      end;
      end;
```

All the logic is performed but the form is closed once Load button is clicked since its entering the finally statements. Any way I can keep the form from closing until I click OK or Cancel?

I need to perform necessary actions in Form1 if I click OK button in Form 2. So, I dont want to move the closing part to OK buttonclick event.

Can you please suggest me on this one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then there must be something that closes the form in your Load button click handler code (assigning value different from `mrNone` to `ModalResult`, or calling `Close` ?).

Comment: Can you show us the `LoadClick button event` ?

Comment: I have updated the code for btnLoadClick.

Comment: @TLama : There is mrYes and mrNo for another dialog box. Do you think this causes to close the message box?

Comment: No, the `ModalResult` of a button should be valid only for the form it belongs to.

Comment: Somewhere in Form2 you need to be assigning a value to ModalResult, like `ModalResult := mrOK;`. You haven't shown that code. It's not in `btnLoadClick`. Where is it being set?

Answer (score 2):

Search CodeRage 9 for my video on "Have You Embraced Your Inner Software Plumber Yet?" for an in-depth discussion of this general topic.

Basically, you need to define an `OnClose` handler in Form2 that sets `Action := caHide;` otherwise it's set to `caFree` by default, which is not what you want in this case.

Also, FWIW, you don't need `FreeAndNil` on a local var if you aren't going to use it again. `TheForm.Free;` is sufficient.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply. I am a little bit new to Delphi. There is no OnClose. There is OnExit. I have a form like this  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl; I have a pagecontrol in that form. Also, I might be missing something, but why do I want to hide the form? I want to form2 to be open and visible until I click OK or Cancel. Can you please let me know if I'm missing anything?

Comment: Components have OnExit. The Form has an OnClose event. In the IDE viewing the form, click on the form (not on a component on the form!) and go to Object Inspector -> Events tab. Look for OnClose. Double-click it. Set `Action := caHide;` If you don't the default is `caFree`. If it's freed when the form closes, then you cannot access anything after ShowModal returns because it's gone. You want to HIDE it, then access the contents, then free it. Watch my CodeRage 9 video; it may not make a lot of sense, but there's a lot of value there for you to learn from. It also talks about this exact topic.

Comment: Note: OnClose is inherited and is ALWAYS CALLED, even if you don't declare an instance of it, which is why you need to do it in this case. The default behavior if you don't override it is to set `Action := caFree;` You haven't shown any code inside of the blocks after testing `Response = mrOK` but I bet that if you try debugging it, you'll get an exception when you try to access `Form2.anything`.